# Could not boot up the laptop until BIOS is reset

Tags: windows-7, boot, bios, battery

I meet a strange problem recently which did not happen before. My *acer E5-471g* laptop could not boot up though the battery is full. I press the boot up button and nothing happens. And I unplug the battery and reset the BIOS. The laptop could boot up again! I am very confused. The default BIOS is **UEFI**, my laptop is **legacy**. My OS is Win7 64bits.

I think the problem is related to software. But I did not install strange apps recently.

Comment: Are you having a problem now or are you just looking for suggestions why you had a problem?

Comment: @Appleoddity I have a problem now and I want solution to solve it.

Comment: Can you [edit] your post and please clarify what problem you have right now? Your post is confusing and it sounds as if things are working now after you reset your BIOS.

Comment: @Appleoddity Things are working after I reset my BIOS. But the same case happens several times. About 2-3 days once

Answer (score 0):

If this happens only occasionally, it may be caused by static electricity. Try disconnecting the power supply, unplugging the battery, then press and hold the power button for more than one minute to discharge the static electricity, and then check if there is such a problem.

If you have such a problem every time you turn it on, try the above method to release static electricity.

If it does not work, it is recommended to go to laptop after-sales department refresh the BIOS.

If it still exists , it may be a hardware problem(motherboard problem). It is recommended to go to the laptop after-sales department to detect the problem.

Comment: Hi, the same case happens several times. This problem would happen in about 4 days. I would try to discharge the electricity firstly. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Hi Daisy, I have tried your first advice. But I could not boot up the computer after holding the power button and plugging the battery. So I unpluged the battery again and did not do anything except waiting for a few seconds. This time works

Comment: I am so glad your issue has been resolved.

Comment: The situation happens agian. The problem is unsolved. Maybe I should go to after-sales dept.